# mongodb query with mongoose in any Objectid

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a schema as follows

```
var S = new Schems({
  f : Mixed
})
```

mongoose.model('collection', S);

How do I query the 'collection' such that i find the documents where `f` is ANY mongo `ObjectId`?

eg if '

```
collection' = [{ f: ObjectId('549138f19f52f268c717a8a2'), _id : 1 },
{ f : ObjectId('549139129f52f268c717a8a4'), _id : 2 }, { f : false, _id :3  }  ]
```

the result should have with _id 1 and 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking for the [**`$type`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) operator. ObjectId types are type "7":

```
Collection.find({ "f": { "$type": 7 } },function(err,docs) {
   // results in here

});
```